# Let $A = I -(x^{*}x) ^{-1} (xx^*)$, where $x$ is a nonzero $n$ -column vectors .Then find

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = I -(x^{*}x) ^{-1} (xx^*)$, where  $x$ is  a nonzero $n$ -column vectors . where  $x^*$ denote  the conjugate transpose .  Then find

$a$)  Rank A

$b)$ Im A

$c)$  kerA

My attempts  : $A = I -(x^{*}x) ^{-1} (xx^*)=I -\frac{xx^*}{x^{*}x}= I -  I =0$

Now  i get  $A  = 0 $..that  is  $Rank A = Im A = 0$ and $Ker A = n$

is Its correct or  Not ??

Any hints /solution will be aappreciated

thanks u

Comment: Not correct. 1. $\frac{xx^*}{x^*x}\ne I$, try some easy $x$ like $(1\ 0)^T$ to see it. 2. $\ker A$ is a subspace, not a number.

Comment: @A.Γ......can u  elaborate  more,,,as  im finding diffuclty

Answer (score 2):

Consider an orthonormal basis $\{x, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$.
What is $Ax$? What is $A v_i$?

> By direct computation, you can check that $Ax = 0$ and $Av_i = v_i$ for all $i$. Thus the kernel of $A$ is the span of $x$. Also, the image of $A$ is the span of $\{v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$, i.e. the orthogonal complement of $x$, and the rank of $A$ can be computed immediately.

Comment: what is the value  of A ? i mean what  is  A?

Comment: @stupid $A = I - (x^*x)^{-1} xx^*$ is the matrix given in your question

Comment: @Yes i know  that .

Comment: ......@ angryv      But  i  want  to know  that  is  $A =  0$  ?

Comment: @stupid No, the attempt in your original post is not correct. As someone pointed out, you seem to use $\frac{xx^*}{x^*x} = I$ which is not correct.